# Android and Mysql Database Communication

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database

- Apps like Spotify and Instagram that their database, how fast users
  to click on buttons respond? How quickly without having to process
  the information stored in the database?
- For example: the Spotify app, I quickly click on the follow button (a
  very rapid clicks). In this case, how information is stored in a
  database?
- What is the best way to connect to the database and managing lots of
  connections?
- Should I use the database interface? example: android sqlite
- In the application Instagram, when I click on the button Like I
  quickly what happens? When information is stored in a database?

(i use volley library)

thanks

Comment: Ideally, you should call an API but not on the main thread in Android. This API will insert/delete (based on like and unlike) an entry in a DB which you can then use to aggregate and store in a different summary column or table which will be updated periodically with a crontab. This can then be used to query with very low latencies

Comment: @KaranShah Would you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take an example scenario, when you hit a like button

> 1. the first thing to do is to store in your local DB that a user has liked a particular artist
> 2. Based on this, you should call an API off your backend which will record this event. But this has to be asynchronous and you shouldn't
>      run this on the Main thread
> 3. Before you wait for a response from the API, you can go ahead and update the Android view based on the local like counter (you can use
>      sqllite for this)
> 4. The backend will run a cronjob to get the total amount of likes and put them into another table column
> 5. So when a new user comes after the cronjob, he/she will see the updated counter

Comment: You can do a simple Google search and check. It isn't that complex. Which language are you using for the backend?

Comment: Please do a simple Google search, you should be able to find existing questions on SO as well