# Create count column for each artist or get count in query (count followers)

Tags: mysql, sql

My app has more than 100 thousand users.

I have two tables:

- artists `id(PK), name, ... , (followers) --> need???`
- following `artist_id, user_id` (both PK)

I need get number of followers For each of the artists.

So which is more logical and more correct? (**Memory and CPU**)

A:

```
select id, name, followers
from artist
limit 30
```

B:

```
SELECT c.*, COUNT(b.artist_id) AS `followers`
FROM (SELECT a.id, a.name
    FROM artists a
    INNER JOIN following b ON a.id = b.artist_id AND b.user_id = ?) AS c
LEFT JOIN following b ON c.id = b.artist_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY `followers` DESC
limit 30
```

Comment: The two queries do different things.  One does what you want.  That is the one you should use.

Comment: Concur with @GordonLinoff, use the second one

Comment: @KaranShah my question edited. if i create columns for artist table and insert count followers in it, is better? or no need to create extra column. (use direct query to get count)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be quicker to get the data with method A but the data might be stale as it might not reflect the true count. (You will have to keep on updating the count with method A on a periodic basis)

With method B, it will be slower but you will a real time count. If it's not important to show the count on a real time basis then I would suggest that you go with method A and then update the follower count on a periodic basis

Comment: real time not important, but using by method B i no need to udpate count col `followers = followers + 1`. I want to know method B is slow and high consumption of server resources?

Comment: @frzdno that's not the question you asked, so we can't answer it

Comment: Using Method A as well, you don't need to do a followers+1, you can just run a cronjob or a MySQL event to update the followers in the artists table. And yes B will be slower because it will consume a lot more CPU and memory

Comment: @KaranShah please answer my another question. [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884357/android-and-mysql-database-communication)